# Performance issues when doing a simple aggregation with ST_WITHIN on large tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql-10

I want to sum the values (population) that are associated with points geometry within a grid element. Here is my approach:

```
CREATE TABLE population_world_grid AS (
    SELECT world_grid.gid as gid, SUM(population_world_point.population)
    FROM world_grid
    INNER JOIN population_world_point ON ST_WITHIN(population_world_point.geometry, world_grid.geometry)
    WHERE population_world_point.population > 0
    GROUP BY world_grid.gid
);
```

Table population_world_point: A table of ~65 millions rows, with a point geometry (SRID 4326) and a population value.

Table world_grid: A table of ~4.5M rows, with polygons covering the world (rectangles)

They both have an GIST index, both have been VACUUMed ANALYZEd, both have been CLUSTERed and reANALYZEd after.

```
QUERY PLAN                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=874109412210.97..874810545217.29 rows=4147187 width=12)
   Group Key: world_grid.gid
   ->  Sort  (cost=874109412210.97..874343109389.12 rows=93478871260 width=8)
         Sort Key: world_grid.gid
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=112.83..850685571873.78 rows=93478871260 width=8)
               ->  Seq Scan on population_world_point  (cost=0.00..6625576.20 rows=67620930 width=36)
                     Filter: (population > 0)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on world_grid  (cost=112.83..12566.29 rows=1382 width=124)
                     Recheck Cond: (geometry ~ population_world_point.geometry)
                     Filter: _st_contains(geometry, population_world_point.geometry)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on world_grid_gix  (cost=0.00..112.48 rows=4147 width=0)
                           Index Cond: (geometry ~ population_world_point.geometry)
(12 rows)
```

From my limited understanding of the EXPLAIN results, it seems that my index on my larger table are not used, possibly because they must all be parsed anyway once we are past the >0 filter?

My issue is that it's been running for several hours with no results, when I was expecting some better performance (perhaps wrongfully so). It took less time to upload all the data though...

What can I do to improve my performance? It seems that my tables, while large, are not that crazy big either... And I'm not doing anything really intensive like Union or Intersection.

My system:

```
PostgreSQL 10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

POSTGIS="2.5.2 r17328" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" (core procs from "2.5.0 r16836" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.5.0 r16836" need upgrade)
```

---

As an aside, I was curious and tried to remove the WHERE condition to see the impact:

```
CREATE TABLE population_world_grid_0 AS (
    SELECT world_grid.gid as gid, SUM(population_world_point.population)
    FROM world_grid
    INNER JOIN population_world_point ON ST_WITHIN(population_world_point.geometry, world_grid.geometry)
    GROUP BY world_grid.gid
);



                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=9230.46..3926502725115.69 rows=4147187 width=12)
   Group Key: world_grid.gid
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9230.46..3924304483872.44 rows=439639954275 width=8)
         ->  Index Scan using world_grid_pkey on world_grid  (cost=0.43..13502174.43 rows=4147187 width=124)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on population_world_point  (cost=9230.03..945193.60 rows=106009 width=36)
               Recheck Cond: (world_grid.geometry ~ geometry)
               Filter: _st_contains(world_grid.geometry, geometry)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on population_world_point_idx  (cost=0.00..9203.53 rows=318028 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (world_grid.geometry ~ geometry)
(9 rows)
```

What I'm seeing when running the two different queries on my database is an interesting behavior:

```
$ top

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                       
10722 postgres  20   0 2132052 1.819g 146932 D  41.7 23.5  93:56.54 postgres                      
30974 postgres  20   0  691980 471284 150780 D   1.7  5.8  19:34.69 postgres
```

The query with the WHERE clause is ramping up in my memory, slowly but surely increasing the %MEM used, the %CPU varying between 1% and 98% roughly. The query without the WHERE clause is staying at a very low %CPU and %MEM. This is something I was not expecting at all, and it worries me as I may very well crash my machine before execution is done (if ever...)

Comment: I've had issues at PG 9.4/9.5 with `ST_Within` using expected indexes, to the point that I use `t.geom && j.geom and ST_Within(t.geom,j.geom)` as a matter of course. Your use of `ST_Within` against a regular grid leaves you vulnerable to losing all points that are coincident to polygon boundaries.

Comment: Yeah I could technically miss some point in a general case, but my data is such that I cannot have this issue. Good point using && to "force" the index being used, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: ...for point in a *regular* grid, without explicitly excluding border cases, there's no need for `ST_Within` at all? just use `&&`.

Comment: Very good point ThingumaBob